# how to read char from a string in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string `a = "aabbbffdshhh"`.  I want to write a program which will give me output of `"a2b3f2d1s1h3"`.  I want to return each letter in the alphabet present and it's count.

The code I am currently using is:

```
int cnta;int cntb; int cntf; int cnth;

for (int i=0;i<a.lenghth;i++)
{
   if(a[i]=='a')
   {
      cnta++;
   }
   if(a[i]=='b')
   {
      cntb++;
   }
   if(a[i]=='h')
   {
   cnth++;
   }
}
```

It is giving me the output but this logic not good.  What other algorithms or approaches could I use?

Comment: Are you trying compress the data?

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Comment: let's say `a = "aaabbaa"` -- what is the desired output?

Comment: And C# doesn't have a lowercase `length` (much less `lenghth`) property on strings. (Or likely any class.)

Comment: This looks like a question normally seen on a programming test. We don't like helping people to cheat, don't ask for "a good idea", ask for specific things.  

Another thing you should do is show that you have done some research on the subject. This looks like a RLE (run length encoding) algorithm. If you even googled that, you probably wouldn't be asking this question.  

TL;DR Be more specific and clear.

Answer (score 11):

This should give you all of the data that you need for your results.

You should be able to append them into a string (using a `StringBuilder`) if you need the results in that format.

```
var results = s.GroupBy(c => c)
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Letter = group.Key,
        Count = group.Count()
    });
```

Comment: Question isn't clear, but if it is some kind of run-length encoding as Austin Salonen mentioned, then your answer does not `give all of the data that OP needs for his/her results.`

Comment: @L.B take a look at the OP's code sample.  That's not what it's trying to do.  He has already said that it's essentially don't what he wants, he just knows it's not a very good approach to solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to have a `List<Tuple<char,int>>` where you pre-populate with each `char` and `0` for it.

Increment the value of each character when encountered.

```
for (int i=0;i<a.lenghth;i++)
{
  myList.Single(t => t.Item1 == a[i]).Item2++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in general terms:

1. sort characters to obtain a sorted list with 1 instance of each char
2. create a list of counters the same size as the sorted list (each counter starts at 0)
3. loop over each char in the string incrementing the corosponding counters
4. loop over the sorted list constructing the result from the sorted list and counters.

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "aabbbffdshhh";

var characters = input.ToArray();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
characters.ToList().ForEach(c=>{if(!sb.ToString().Contains(c)){sb.Append(c); sb.Append(characters.ToList().Count(cc=>cc == c));}});

//sb.ToString().Dump(); //output is a2b3f2d1s1h3
```

Done in LinqPad

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary of type Dictionary.  On the first occurrence add to the dictionary, on every subsequent increment.

This way you can use whatever characters you want (and control how to treat case) rather than just handling the 26

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're doing a slight variation of [Run-length Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding), this will encode your string.  My comment went unanswered so I'm posing this as a guess.  I'll leave the decoding as an exercise to you (or just check out rosettacode to see the implementation).

```
var a = "aabbbffdshhh";
var rle = new StringBuilder();

var last = a[0];
var count = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    if (a[i] != last)
    {
        rle.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", last, count);
        last = a[i];
        count = 0;
    }

    count++;
}

rle.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", last, count);

Assert.AreEqual("a2b3f2d1s1h3", rle.ToString());
```

Comment: @sof_engi08:  If this was particularly helpful, the rule of thumb is to accept it as the answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with 1 line of super readable code (sarcasm) :-) I have added an orderby even though this wasn't requested, you can remove if needed.

```
        string a = "aaaadjkhsdfkjsdjkfhsdkjff";
        var res = a.GroupBy(c => c).OrderBy(g => g.Key).Aggregate("", (p, g) => p += g.Key + g.Count().ToString());
```

or if you are one of those who think string concatenation is too inefficient

```
        var res2 = a.GroupBy(c => c).OrderBy(g => g.Key).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (p, g) => p.Append(g.Key + g.Count().ToString())).ToString();;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        string a = "aaabbbasdlfjasldfkjalsdkfjaewoasdfj";

        //store character counts in a dictionary 
        Dictionary<char, int> charCounts = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        //iterate through string and place counts in dictionary
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!charCounts.Keys.Contains(a[i]))
            {
                charCounts[a[i]] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                charCounts[a[i]] += 1;
            }
        }

        //output sorted list
        foreach (char letter in charCounts.Keys.OrderBy(x => x))
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0}{1}", letter, charCounts[letter]));
        }
```

Comment: yes thanks it is working,i was not aware of Dictionary class ,can we do this without dictionary class.

Answer (score 0):

in C# you could do:

```
Dictionary<char, int> d = new Dictionary<char, int>();
foreach(char c in a){
    if(d.ContainsKey(c)){
        d[c] = d[c] + 1;
    } else {
        d[c] = 1;
    }
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(KeyValuePair p in d){
    sb += p.Key.ToString() + p.Value.Tostring();
}
return sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

this code should work in cpp

```
int* count = new int[26];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
  count[a[i] - 'a']++;
```

in c# you will need to play around a little so you well look at a char as a number.